# Does AES/CBC/NoPadding generates two different Cipher texts even though the input is same?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes, cbc-mode

Using the following code, I am doing AES encrypt operation, I am passing the same input at different instances but I am getting different Cipher. Why does this happen?

```
 public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] plainText, byte[] key) 
    {
  byte[] passwordKey128 = Arrays.copyOfRange(key, 0, 16);
  SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(passwordKey128, "AES");
  Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
  cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
  byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);
  return cipherText;
 }
```

Input is

```
 encrypt(new byte[]{-17, -60, -70, 24, 80, 35, 2, -62, -79, 19, -55, -50, -62, -69, -80, -96} ,new byte[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} );
```

At one instance cipher is - [0, 91, -96, 80, -44, -93, 107, 62, 4, -10, 103, 119, 109, 4, 25, 68]

At another instance cipher is - [87, 109, 20, 69, 18, 6, 103, 92, -57, 62, -41, -103, -18, -19, 74, 87]

What can be the reason?

Comment: In addition, don't use CBC mode in conjunction with "NoPadding" unless your data size is always a multiple of 16 byte - it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CBC mode requires an IV and the `init` method may generate a random IV if none is specified (from [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#init-int-java.security.Key-)):

> If this cipher requires any algorithm parameters that cannot be derived from the given key, the underlying cipher implementation is supposed to generate the required parameters itself (using provider-specific default or random values) if it is being initialized for encryption or key wrapping, and raise an InvalidKeyException if it is being initialized for decryption or key unwrapping. The generated parameters can be retrieved using getParameters or getIV (if the parameter is an IV).

To avoid that specify an IV explicitly.